# Throttle Download Speed of CefSharp

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I created an application which is basically a website wrapper for a music website. It's a winform with CefSharp. Now, every time the song changes, there's a huge bandwidth load and I want to reduce it. I think there is no easy implementation for CefSharp and I can't use filestreams because I can't get the download url etc.

Is there a way to control the bandwidth of the whole application?

Comment: Is it a flash based media player or HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

The `CEF` framework for which `CefSharp` is based does not support this feature.

See below link for response from `CEF` maintainer

http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=13373#p27423

Answer (score 0):

speed can be limited by windows per process

- [How to Limit Any Application’s Bandwidth on Windows (HowToGeek)](https://www.howtogeek.com/347711/how-to-limit-any-applications-bandwidth-on-windows/#:%7E:text=To%20configure%20this%2C%20head%20to,in%20the%20background%E2%80%9D%20option%20here.)
- [Way to limit bandwidth of programs on Windows? (SuperUser)](https://superuser.com/questions/135719/way-to-limit-bandwidth-of-programs-on-windows)